# EX Series Switch Efficient BPDU Protect Statements

Tags: juniper, juniper-ex, cli

Is there an efficient way to explicitly configure all interfaces as edge ports except for one or two?  Something along the lines of:

```
set protocols rstp interface all edge

set protocols rstp interface ge-0/0/0 mode point-to-point

set protocols rstp interface ge-0/0/1 mode point-to-point

set protocols rstp interface all bpdu-timeout-action block

set protocols rstp interface all bpdu-timeout-action log

set protocols rstp bpdu-block-on-edge
```

Comment: Are you just looking at a way of automating the statements or are you trying to eliminate redundant configurations?  The `wildcard range` stanza might be [your simplest solution](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1/topics/example/junos-cli-wildcard-range-configuring.html) if your trying to apply something like this en masse.

Comment: That might be the solution that I end up using, however it would be nice if there was a way to use an except type of command.  Say, for the access-layer having everything edge except it's single uplink.  Can you give me an example of how I would use the wildcard range for this?

Comment: Since this is Juniper related I can't give a real answer, but in Cisco-Land the `spanning-tree portfast default` command only applies to interfaces set in `switchport mode access`, which allows you to either configure a trunked interface, or in the interface configuration use `spanning-tree portfast disable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by your comments, you're simply trying to simplify your initial `set` statements.  The easiest solution is to use the `wildcard range` statements released after 12.1.

Example usage:

```
user@host# wildcard range set interfaces ge-0/0/[0-23] unit 0 family vpls
```

Equivalent to:

```
user@host# set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family vpls
user@host# set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family vpls
user@host# set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family vpls
...
user@host# set interfaces ge-0/0/23 unit 0 family vpls
```

<sup>[Juniper - Example: Using the Wildcard Command with the Range Option](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1/topics/example/junos-cli-wildcard-range-configuring.html#config-1)</sup>

In your example above, you appear to want to [multiple ranges](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1/topics/example/junos-cli-wildcard-range-configuring.html#jd0e230).  For instance, if you wanted all ports except port 25, you would use this:

```
wildcard range set protocols rstp interface ge-0/0/[0-24,26-47] mode point-to-point
```